# Recuperar información de input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Tengo un modal que lo que hago es agregar input y a cada uno le pongo una id según el numero, ejemplo pregunta0 , pregunta1.
El total de preguntas lo obtengo de una variable total donde almaceno el numero que hay.
Ahora lo que intento es recuperar el valor que tienen esos input en ese modal para mostrarlo en la parte web donde muestro otra vez los input creados.

```
$( "#agregarPreguntas" ).click(function() {

  $('#preguntas').modal('toggle');

  var p = document.getElementById('addpregunta2').innerHTML;
  var valores = [];
  for(i=0 ; i<=total ; i++){
    valores[i] = document.getElementById('pregunta'+i).value;
 }

 document.getElementById("contenedorPreguntas").innerHTML = "<div class='row'>"+p+"</div>";

 });
```

Este es mi codigo pero me falla en el for cuando intento acceder a 'pregunta'+i me pone que es null pero si existe

Comment: Podrías agregar tu código html también?

Comment: @daniellandete ya que utilizas jquery porque no recoger los datos de esta manera 
valores[i] = $('#pregunta' + i ).val(); I como dice el compañero de arriba deberías poner el HTML, seguro que nos ayuda más a buscar una solución.

Comment: Está obteniendo null por que no encuentra el elemento Id del dom, entonces `null.value` genera un error ya que el objeto null no tiene la propiedad value.